# Making Inequalities Neat

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How do I make my inequalities neat? I find the horizontal spacing between all my `<` symbols horrendous. And I feel the same way about the vertical distorition caused by `\cfrac`.

```
Suppose $\delta < \cfrac{1}{2}$ 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    |x| < \sqrt{\epsilon} < \cfrac{1}{2} & \Rightarrow |x^2| < \epsilon < \cfrac{1}{4} \\
    & \Rightarrow |-x^2| < \epsilon < \cfrac{1}{4}  \\
    & \Rightarrow - \cfrac{1}{4} < -\epsilon < -x^2 < \epsilon < \cfrac{1}{4} \\
    & \Rightarrow \cfrac{3}{4} < 1 - x^2 < \epsilon + 1 < \cfrac{5}{4} \\
    & \Rightarrow  \sqrt{1-x^2} < \sqrt{\epsilon + 1} < \epsilon + 1\\ 
    & \Rightarrow |\sqrt{1-x^2}| < \sqrt{\epsilon + 1} < \epsilon +1 \\
    |x| < \sqrt{\epsilon} < \cfrac{1}{2} &\Rightarrow |\sqrt{1-x^2}| < \epsilon + 1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you want to change?  What do you want to do with the horizontal and vertical spacing?

Comment: I guess how to remove vertical distorion caused by `\cfrac`, and how to give greater horizontal space to all the `<` symbols.

Comment: perhaps use a dual alignment on both `\Rightarrow` and a suitable `<`, this requires that you use `alignedat` or `aligned` instead of `split` as `split` only allows a single alignment point

Comment: You shouldn't be using `\cfrac` to begin with, but a plain `\frac` (in the first occurrence possibly `\dfrac`). I see nothing “horrendous* about the spacing of `<`. Rather, you should use `\lvert -x^2\rvert` to fix the wrong spacing.

Comment: By the way, your first line should be `Suppose $\epsilon<\dfrac{1}{4}$.`

Answer (score 1):

Here's probably how I'd do it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir} %just because that is the default class in my editor
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\begin{document}
Suppose $\delta < \frac{1}{2}$ 
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    && \abs{x} &< \sqrt{\epsilon} < \tfrac{1}{2}
    \\
    & \Rightarrow \quad&\abs{x^2} &< \epsilon < \tfrac{1}{4}
    \\
    & \Rightarrow &\abs{-x^2} &< \epsilon < \tfrac{1}{4}
    \\
    & \Rightarrow &- \tfrac{1}{4} &< -\epsilon < -x^2 < \epsilon <
    \tfrac{1}{4}
    \\
    & \Rightarrow &\tfrac{3}{4} &< 1 - x^2 < \epsilon + 1 < \tfrac{5}{4}
    \\
    & \Rightarrow &\sqrt{1-x^2} &< \sqrt{\epsilon + 1} < \epsilon + 1
    \\
    & \Rightarrow &\abs{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &< \sqrt{\epsilon + 1} < \epsilon
    +1
    \\
    && \abs{x} &< \sqrt{\epsilon} < \tfrac{1}{2}
    \\
    &\Rightarrow & \abs{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &< \epsilon + 1
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```